# Connecting unused input 74LS07 gate

Tags: digital-logic, open-collector

This is open collector gate.

I [can not find](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls07.pdf) the amount of the leakage current through the input.

Also not clear what output configuration must be to minimize current: leaving it floating - then with what input state? Connecting pull-up resistor - with what input state?

I would consider putting no resistor at the output at all, having output transistor turned on (~ground on the output), thus having input connected to ground (what would be a leakage current?).

Is it correct decision?

Comment: If dealing with few inputs, simply connect the inputs together. The input current does not change significantly at all with input connected together. Look at the datasheet.

Comment: Jack, I am more concerned of what to do with OC output...

Comment: Outputs can be left open.

Comment: Input currents are specified in section 6.5 of the datasheet you linked to.

Comment: As per the datasheet, for low input voltage, leakage 200uA max, for high input, it is 20uA. So, I'd tie them to the +VCC if unused and I care a lot about leakage.

Comment: @ThePhoton perfect, thank you. Overlooked this! From datasheet it is not clear what input leakage current would be if connecting input to Vcc, but I suspect the currents are comparable, thus should be no matter to connect to Vcc or GND.

Comment: @Big6 thank you, 20 uA is listed for 2.4 V input though, @5 V it could (and will be) different, but not that much.

Comment: @Anonymous, it's a TTL style input (see page 7), the \$I_{IH}\$ spec (with 2.4 V) is probably current out of the pin, not into it. At VCC it should be lower. (with some leakage into the protection diode).

Answer (score 1):

See Section 6.5 of the data sheet you linked. Iih and Iil are the numbers you are looking for.

Iih is the input current when the input is held high (nominally 2.4 volts for TTL/LSTTL) and in this case is 20 uA.

Iil is the input current when the input is held low (nominally 0.4 volts), and in this case is -200 uA. The "-" indicates that current is flowing out of the input, and you need to sink this current, rather than source it.

Answer (score 0):

From the schematic on page 7 you can see that the lowest current would be with the input grounded.

With the input high the second transistor would be conducting about 800uA to drive the output stage.

With the input low there is 200uA though the input resistor but the rest of the circuit will not conduct any significant current.